# How to access Obsolete variables in graph extension

Tags: acumatica

I have field declared with obsolete in some other project, how i can access this field in my extended graph.

```
    [Obsolete("Use AMShiftMst.shiftType", true)]
    public abstract class shftDiff : IBqlField, IBqlOperand
    {
        protected shftDiff();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use this class `shftDiff` because the `ObsoleteAttribute` marks any usage as an error. The message in the obsolete call mentions the new object to use.

See `ObsoleteAttribute(String, Boolean)` here:
[ObsoleteAttribute Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.obsoleteattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)

However related to the product it looks like the message should indicate to use `AMShiftMst.shftDiff` and not `AMShiftMst.shiftType` as `shiftType` doesn't exist.

Using `AMShiftMSt.shftDiff` should solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks Brendan, for your inputs, actually i wanna hide the field, so i did it through Access Rights

Comment: that will work, but at the same time the page shouldn't have a reference to the obsolete field and then there would be no need for access rights.